# calling a method into another function

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't the updatePosition read the fall function in Square? Its suppose to be drawing a block falling from the top, but nothing is happening. Can't seem to wrap my head around the problem. It has something to do with invoking a function call within another.

```
 var WIDTH = 300,
    HEIGHT = 400,
    c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

setInterval(function () {
    clearCanvas();
    updatePosition();
    drawOnCanvas();
}, 1000 / 50);

var clearCanvas = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'White';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

var drawLine = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var updatePosition = function () {
    Square.fall();

}

var drawOnCanvas = function () {
    drawLine();
    Square.draw();
}

var speedLevels = [20, 16, 12, 10, 8],
    currSpeed = speedLevels[0];

var Square = function (speed) {
    var self = this;
    self.color = "Black";
    self.vPosition = 0;
    self.hPosition = 4;
    self.speed = speed;
    self.temp = 0;

    self.fall = function () {
        if (self.temp == self.speed) {
            self.vPosition++;
            self.temp = 0;
        }
        self.temp++;
    }

    self.draw = function () {
        console.log(self.vPosition * squareLength);
        ctx.fillStyle = self.color;
        ctx.fillRect(self.hPosition * squareLength, self.vPosition * squareLength, squareLength, squareLength);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: "Why doesn't the updatePosition read the fall function in Square" how do you know it doesnt? any errors in your dev console? do breakpoints fire?

Comment: `Square` in your code is a **constructor**, not _object_ (instance). But you use it in `updatePosition` as object which is wrong. `Square` has no `fall` method, its instance (if created) will have.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're calling `Square.fall()` and `Square.draw()` as if `Square` were an instance of an object - it's not, because you haven't done `Square = new ...` anywhere.

Secondly, you're using a variable `squareLength` which isn't defined anywhere.

```js
var _Square = function(speed) {
  var self = this;
  self.color = "Black";
  self.vPosition = 0;
  self.hPosition = 4;
  self.speed = speed;
  self.temp = 0;
  squareLength = 1;

  self.fall = function() {
    if (self.temp == self.speed) {
      self.vPosition++;
      self.temp = 0;
    }
    self.temp++;
  }

  self.draw = function() {
    console.log(self.vPosition * squareLength);
    ctx.fillStyle = self.color;
    ctx.fillRect(self.hPosition * squareLength, self.vPosition * squareLength, squareLength, squareLength);
  }
  return self;
}

var WIDTH = 300,
  HEIGHT = 400,
  c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var Square = new _Square(10);

setInterval(function() {
  clearCanvas();
  updatePosition();
  drawOnCanvas();
}, 1000 / 50);

var clearCanvas = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'White';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

var drawLine = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 400);
  ctx.stroke();
}

var updatePosition = function() {
  Square.fall();

}

var drawOnCanvas = function() {
  drawLine();
  Square.draw();
}

var speedLevels = [20, 16, 12, 10, 8],
  currSpeed = speedLevels[0];
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```